# Custom designated initializer with BOOL parameter and exception?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

My question is probably very simple to answer. 
I have a custom written designated initializer that gets in a BOOL parameter.

In it, I want to check whether there was a BOOL passed or something else.
If something else, I want to raise an exception.

I also want to override the default init and point it to my designated intializer instead of calling super, and pass a nil in there so that the user gets the proper exception when he is not using the designated initializer.

```
-(id)init
{
  return [self initWithFlag:nil];
} 


-(id)initWithFlag:(BOOL)flag
{
    //get the super self bla bla

    if (flag IS-NOT-A-BOOL)
    {
        //raising exception here
    }
    //store the flag

    return self;
}
```

What should be in place of IS-NOT-A-BOOL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BOOL in objective c can result in either YES or NO, and everything will be casted to one of those values. How about using an **NSNumber** containing a bool value? Like:

```
 -(id)initWithFlag:(NSNumber *)flag
{
    //get the super self bla bla

    if (!flag) // Check whether not nil
    {
        //raising exception here
        [NSException raise:@"You must pass a flag" format:@"flag is invalid"];
    }
    //store the flag
    BOOL flagValue = [flag boolValue];

    return self;
}
```

In this case you could call the method like this

```
[self initWithFlag:@YES]; // or @NO, anyway, it won't throw an exception
```

or this

```
[self initWithFlag:nil]; // it will throw an exception
```

Comment: Explicit boxing is unnecessary with Boolean literals.  `@YES` and `@NO` work just fine.